# Is there a list of special skills for Scroll cards?

Tags: scrolls

In Scrolls, as with many card games, your cards can have pre-defined skills (such as "Haste") which offer bonus powers to your units.  When some of these skills appear on cards, they are also defined on the card.  (i.e "Haste: Card comes into play with a countdown of 0.")

However, while glancing at my beginner deck, I noticed that some of these cards appear to have skills without a definition.  For instance, the Crossbowman has a skill called "Ranged Attacks" but what that means isn't defined.

Is there a list within or game, or some where else, explaining what these skills are and what they do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This Wiki](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/index.php/Scrolls_Database) (there are probably more Wikis too) shows a comprehensive list of all scrolls currently in the game. The special talents (like "Ranged attacks") are also explained: [Ranged attack](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/index.php/Ranged_Attack)

Answer (score 8):

You can get an explanation of the various abilities by viewing the card in game, and hovering your mouse over them.

This works in the Deck Builder:
[image]

And in matches:
[image]

Comment: Mouse-hover... I don't know why I didn't think of that.  Thank you.

Comment: On Android (and iOS I assume) if you click on the text box it'll "flip" the card and show you all of the special rules (since tablets generally don't have mice).

Answer (score 1):

From the ScrollsGuide team, there is this App on Android:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kbasten.scrollsapp

The description says:

> **Description**
>
> A Guide to Scrolls is a reference to accompany every Scrolls player.
>   It's the most complete collection of information about every scroll
>   available, and features community-written tutorials for the latest
>   game by Mojang.
>
> With this app, you can:
>
> - Know everything! Look up categorized info about *every* scroll.
> - Stay up to date! Read official news directly from Mojang.
> - Find specific scrolls! Sift out scrolls by resource or type.
> - Learn from others! Read up on the latest strategy & techniques with community-written guides.
> - Rank yourself! See the top Scrolls players, realtime. Search functionality and ranking graphs to see stats for every player.
> - Know when to play! See full game statistics.
>
> It doesn't cost a thing and is completely ad-free.

Comment: Could you clarify "From the developers"? I don't see any evidence that this app is from Mojang.

Comment: The app is from Koen Basten who is not a developer, but he is part of the ScrollsGuide team (src: http://www.scrollsguide.com/users/kbasten). I'll update the answer