# How does poison affect a unit in Scrolls?

Tags: scrolls

I have searched and searched, but have been unable to find a description of the "poison" mechanic in Mojang Scrolls.  I would appreciate an explanation.

Comment: This related post should answer your question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/119696/is-there-a-list-of-special-skills-for-scroll-cards

Comment: That is wrong, this is an entirely different question. And [a subset is _not_ a duplicate](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/is-a-question-a-duplicate-just-because-it-asks-for-something-that-can-be-part-of), especially if the "superset" question only asks about a location in the internet

Comment: Ah, the second paragraph turned this into a partial duplicate - titaniumdecoy, please ask only one question per post (unless they are really strongly correlated) since in the end there should be _one_ correct answer and not multiple ones each of which is only partially a solution. Read more on the [about page](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/about) - you even get a shiny badge just for reading that

Answer (score 2):

Poison is used by a variety of scrolls in Decay and a few in Growth. All scrolls discussed are Decay unless otherwise stated.

**Poison** is an *effect* which can be applied to *creatures* (not structures). (An effect is a modifier attached to a unit which doesn't count as an enchantment.) It may be applied in several ways, but always has the same result. Quoting from the in-game description on a poisoned unit:

> Unit takes 1 damage at the beginning of owner's turn.

- A unit becoming poisoned does not deal any immediate damage.
- If a unit is poisoned twice (e.g. by applying *Ranger's Bane* twice), they count separately and will deal 1+1 = 2 damage when they trigger.
- When the unit is *healed*, this removes all poison.

Units may become poisoned in several ways; directly by use of *Ranger's Bane* (Growth) or *Brain Lice* (note that *Brain Lice* applies poison and separately its own enchantment for the draw effect), or indirectly by the abilities of another unit (*Vitriol Aura* (Growth), *Bitter Root, Blightbearer, Pest Dissimulator*).

**Poison damage** is a type of non-combat damage. It is increased by Curse enchantments and ignores armor.

*Blightbearer* and *Infectious Blight* are scrolls which receive or deal poison damage but do not use the Poison effect itself; notably, *Infectious Blight* acts very much like poison but does not display the graphic for poisoned units.

*Miasma Well* is a structure which does damage to poisoned units only.

Answer (score 1):

Poison is an ability that is currently only found in two growth enchantments: [Vitriol Aura](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/index.php/Vitriol_Aura) and [Ranger's Bane](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/index.php/Ranger%27s_Bane), although as of writing the Decay deck is currently going through testing, and according to the [Scrolls database](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/index.php/Scrolls_Database) will contain at least 8 other scrolls that utilise Poison.

The ability damages the target creature by 1 hit point at the start of each round for a specified number of rounds.

It's a bit hard to talk about scrolls that are currently in development, but as an aside I notice that [Blightbearer](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/index.php/Blightbearer) will take "poison damage" before it attacks, which is essentially not how the "poison" keyword is usually used. I would hazard a guess that this is simply categorising the damage type, enabling scrolls such as [Miasma Well](http://www.scrollsguide.com/wiki/index.php/Miasma_Well) to modify the effect.